# KeyError getting metadata from video file

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to get the resolution height and the audio bitrate from a video file, but I'm getting the following error that doesn't tell me much:

```
File "/home/user/code/python/reduce_video_size/main.py", line 94, in get_metadata
    return video_streams[0]
KeyError: 0

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.339s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

so I don't know what can I do to fix it.

```
print(get_metadata("/home/user/code/python/reduce_video_size/test.mp4"))

def get_metadata(path):
    video_streams = ffmpeg.probe(path, select_streams = "v")
    if video_streams:
        return video_streams[0]
```

If there's need for more context [here](https://codeberg.org/LifeSymbiont/reduce_video_size/src/branch/main/main.py) is the code.

This solved it but it would still be nice to have some error checking:

```
def get_metadata(path):
    video_stream = ffmpeg.probe(path, select_streams = "v")
    return video_stream['streams'][0]
```

Comment: firstr you could use `print()` to see what you really have in `video_streams`

Comment: maybe you should check `if video_stream['streams']: return video_stream['streams'][0]` or even `if ('streams' in  video_stream) and (video_stream['streams']): return video_stream['streams'][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/ffmpeg/_probe.py), `ffmpeg.probe` returns a dictionary loaded from JSON. So, you don't need to take out the first item and the `[0]` can be omitted. It does obviously not have any integer indices.